# SQL needed to find if a property exists in multiple counties

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need some SQL to determine if a property exists in multiple counties.

I have a list of distinct property ids and county ids, but I'm not sure how to find if the property exists in more than one county.

TABLE:  PROPERTIES

| PROPERTYID | COUNTYID |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1111 |
| 12345 | 1112 |
| 23456 | 1111 |
| 34567 | 2222 |

In this example, I need some sql that will only show me property 12345 since it exists in both county 1111 and 1112.

I'm sure there is some easy SQL, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with SQL syntax, but you have access to SQL Developer, you might try using the in-built [Query Builder](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Querybuilder/sqldev3.0_QB.htm?print=preview) functionality. It will give you a nice graphical interface to work with and you can watch how the SQL forms from your request.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with properties (propertyid, countryid) as
  2    (select 12345, 1111 from dual union all
  3     select 12345, 1112 from dual union all
  4     select 23456, 1111 from dual union all
  5     select 34567, 2222 from dual
  6    )
```

Query:

```
  7  select propertyid
  8  from properties
  9  group by propertyid
 10  having count(distinct countryid) > 1;

PROPERTYID
----------
     12345

SQL>
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much.  I figured it would be easy, but it broke my brain for a minute!